# HerokuApp==> Detected Framework: Static HTML

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a react app to herokuapp but then it gives the following error

```bash
remote: =====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static.git#21c1f5175186b70cf247384fd0bf922504b419be
remote: =====> Detected Framework: Static HTML
remote: Stack heroku-22 is not supported!
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) multi app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Please any advice on how to go about solving the issue?

Comment: It is more useful it you provide people about information for what you have tried to do to debug the issue.